# How do I remove items from DOM and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I am currently attempting to build a list app in which the user inputs an item to the list, and the item entered displays on the page as well as gets pushed into an array called "items".

The part where the item is displayed on the page and gets pushed to the array works just fine, as well as removing the item from the page. Where I've been running into trouble is removing from the array. What happens is that when the item is removed from the DOM, the corresponding array element is not always removed.

It appears that simultaneously removing items from the page and the array is not so easy. And I need to push the items to an array, as this array will be used for something else, which I have already figured out.

Currently, I am attempting to use splice but that doesn't seem to work too well.

I have also tried re-writing this program to where the item gets pushed to the array first, and then, using a for loop, iterate over the array and have the items appear on the  page.

The link below leads to a live version of the app in question. It's hosted on my Neocities account.

Thank you to anyone who can help!

https://chillaxin-cyborg.neocities.org/ListApp.html

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #myList {
            list-style: none;
        }
        li {
            padding: 10px;
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: rgb(186, 255, 129);
            font-size: larger;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-style: double;
            border-radius: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
        }
        .remove-btn {
            float: right;
            background-color: red;
            color:black;
            
        }
        #itemAdd {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: larger;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #itemName {
            padding: 10px;
            max-width: 300px;
            font-size: larger;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-style: double;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container main">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="itemName">
        <button onclick="addItem()" id="itemAdd">ADD</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <ul id="myList">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

        let items = [];

        const addItem = () => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let myList = document.getElementById('myList');
            let listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.innerText = itemName.value + "  ";
            myList.append(listItem);
            let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
            removeButton.innerText = "-";
            removeButton.className = "remove-btn"
            removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
            listItem.append(removeButton);
            items.push(itemName.value);
            document.forms[0].reset();
        }

        const removeItem = () => {
            let item = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
            item.remove();
            let itemIndex = items.indexOf(item);
            items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tried your program. Do a `console.log(itemIndex)` in `removeItem()` and you will probably spot what's wrong. You're only removing the last index in your array, instead of removing from the correct position. It would be easier to have the full code, HTML included, so we can debug the code for you.

Comment: Hello and thank you for replying. My apologies for updating so late. I work night shift and have been a bit run down today.
Anyway, I updated my code to include all HTML, and I also threw in my CSS just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm programming blindly here, so bare with me if the code isn't flawless.

What's wrong is the line `let itemIndex = items.indexOf(item);` where you search an array of string with a node (sort of DOM object).

Instead, add a `data-*` attribute to your `<li>` element, where you add what the user types, and extract that via the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Then use that string to search through your `list` array.

I took the liberty of refactoring some of your code to make it more readable.

```
   let items = [];
   
    var createListItem = (text) => {
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerText = text;
        listItem.setAttribute('data-value', text); // adding a data attribute
        
        return listItem;
    }
    
    var createRemoveButton() {
        let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.innerText = "-";
        removeButton.className = "remove-btn"
        removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
        
        return removeButton;
    }

    const addItem = () => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let userInput = itemName.value.trim();
        let myList = document.getElementById('myList');
        let listItem = createListItem(userInput);

        listItem.append(createRemoveButton());
        myList.append(listItem);
        
        items.push(userInput);
        document.forms[0].reset();
    }

    const removeItem = (event) => {
        let item = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
        let userInput = item.dataset.value; // extracting the data attribute
        item.remove();
        let itemIndex = items.indexOf(userInput);
        items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Wow!, thank you for taking the time to do all of that, my friend. That's very kind of you!
Quick question regarding your updates. I noticed you used var, and seeing as I am still kind of a rookie programmer, what would be the advantage of using "var" over "let" or "const". I know that scope is one difference it has between those two, as var is globallly scoped (I believe).

Comment: I don't create functions like that. Instead, I declare them as `function removeItem(event) {`. It felt wrong to use "const" for something that could be used to create several _different_ items, so I used "var" instead. It's, to me, arbitrary.

Comment: Ahh, okay that makes sense then. I appreciate all your help, man. Thanks!